# Swift Navigation Bar item not calling action

Tags: swift, uibutton, navigation

I have an item on the navigation bar that calls an action. It stopped working. I have disconnected the item from the action and re-attached. Still no action. The action is attached in the storyboard. How do I debug or solve this issue?

Comment: You're going to have to give us more than that. How do you know the IBAction stopped firing? Try putting a `print("Action called")` as the first line in the function and see if that works

Comment: yes I have done that and also place a break in the function and it doesn't break

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

*If you have a parameter*

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "ButtonName", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.yourAction(_:)))

}
```

*Without parameter*

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "ButtonName", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.yourAction))

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you used the drag and drop functionality for creating the IBAction method, make sure it created the method for the button and not the "Bar Button Item."

The easiest way to check is by opening the Document Outline view in your Storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

The key point is the ***target*** parameter, in your issue.

If you don't set ***target: self***, you have no chance to know the method that you called from your class will work or not. The selector method you wanna trigger will behave strangely, sometimes it will work, sometimes not.

You have to set the **self** attribute to your **target** parameter. Not **nil**.

Example usage in code:

```
// trigger func, used from #selector
@objc func selectorMethod() { /*...*/ }

// create the button you wanna set
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "ButtonTitle", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(selectorMethod))

// set the button item to the right bar
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```