# Custom TabViewController - navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem doesn't show up in nav bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm using a custom [TabViewController](https://github.com/bardonadam/SlidingTabBar). I want to change the right bar button item **ONLY in CompanyViewController**. However, changing the `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` doesn't work - **the button doesn't show up on the navigation bar**. How can I fix this?

**CompanyViewController.swift**

```
let filterButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Filters Off", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(filterButtonTapped))

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = filterButton // Works
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = filterButton //Doesn't work
```

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38412621/7327018)

Comment: Try something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39060247/6680583)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code:

```
//Create custom UIButton with image.

let filterButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
filterButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "imagename"), for: .normal)
filterButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
filterButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Class.Methodname), for: .touchUpInside)

//Assign that UIButton to UIBarButtonItem
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: filterButton)

//set UIBarButtonItem to navigationItem
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)
```